# Securing Rsync Daemon Over SSH with NON-root user

Tags: rsync, daemon

Unfortunately, due to hosting provider, I am unable to access the rsync daemon as root and secure it accordingly.  Instead, in order to take regular remote backups from the server, I have to access the rsync daemon as a non-root user that has limited sudo privileges via the `/etc/sudoers` file.

I have managed to get this to work and can successfully take backups, using the solution below (scroll down).
**Additional Info Per Request**
a.) `non-root-username` has this sudo privilege via `/etc/sudoers`:

`non-root-username ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync`

b.) The goal is to use a non-root user to take secure remote backups of my system directory called `/backups` (using encrypted ssh connection and rysncd instead of rsync protocol to save on resources)

c.) a single directory called `/backups` (which can successfully do with the solution below, I just want to make sure it is as secure as possible)

**Question:**
How do I make this non-root-user rsync daemon connection more secure?

**Issues**
Because `sudo rsync` does not save environment variables, I have a variety of issues:

1.) In the `/etc/rsyncd.conf`  the `hosts allow =` function no longer works, server-side rsync.log, shows:

```
rsync allowed access on module data from UNKNOWN (0.0.0.0)
rsync on data/ from root@UNKNOWN (0.0.0.0)
building file list
```

2.) Via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and/or `/home/non-root-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` I am unable to use `ForceCommand`, `command=rsync --server --daemon .`, respectively, for the actual rsync command.  Any attempt to do so results in:

```
rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1675) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

2a.) I currently have these values restricting my non-root-backup-user in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`... any additional recommendations?

```
Match User non-root-username
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTTY no
   # ForceCommand /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/rsync <-- will not work
   # ForceCommand sudo rsync <-- will not work
   # ForceCommand rsync <-- will not work
```

**My current solution:**

Using:
`rsync -a -e "ssh -l non-root-username" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" xx.xx.xx.xx::data /local/path`
**Update:**
The edit the above command caused `@ERROR: auth failed on module data`, therefore I had to change the auth user in the above `/etc/rsyncd.conf` to `auth users: root` and the same for `/etc/rsyncd.conf`

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/rsyncd.conf 
# Global configuration of the rsync service
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
#hosts allow = 123.123.123.123  <-- hashed out
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
# Username and group for working with backups
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
# Data source information
[data]
use chroot = false
#strict modes = false <-- (defaults to true)
path = /backups
list = yes
auth users = root
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.passwd
```

In my `/etc/rsyncd.passwd file`, I have:

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/rsyncd.passwd 
root:password
```

I have these permissions for `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
root@admin:~# stat /etc/rsyncd.conf 
  File: /etc/rsyncd.conf
  Size: 471         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 144028      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/root)
Access: 2022-05-21 13:38:46.797769245 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-21 13:38:42.641735637 +0800
Change: 2022-05-21 13:55:52.384894170 +0800
```

And, I have these permissions for `/etc/rsyncd.passwd`

```
root@admin:~# stat /etc/rsyncd.passwd 
  File: /etc/rsyncd.passwd
  Size: 31          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 144040      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/root)
Access: 2022-05-21 13:38:06.989448597 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-21 13:37:37.473212811 +0800
Change: 2022-05-21 13:37:37.473212811 +0800
```

Any tips?

Comment: A big part of the problem is confusion. Your command looks like you're trying to run `rsync` over `ssh` but then you throw in an `rsyncd` path syntax. This simply doesn't make sense. My strong recommendation would be to stop fiddling with `rsyncd.conf` and indeed if possible switch off `rsyncd`, and instead use `rsync` over `ssh` fully

Comment: @roaima  I edited the the command to look more standard,, according to docs, they work the same exact way... and are generating the same exact issues. feedback welcome.

Comment: It's the double colon in the remote `host::path` - two colons means "use rsync protocol to an rsyncd daemon"; one colon means "use rsync protocol over a transport such as ssh"

Comment: What I'm also not clear about is (a) what root permissions (if any) you have - whether directly or via `sudo`, (b) whether your preference would be to run the transfer over an encrypted `ssh` tunnel or to use an unencrypted `rsyncd` daemon, and (c) how much of the server you're trying to backup. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: @roaima done...